# PHP change whole line if a word exist in a line of .txt file

Tags: php

I'm using `preg_replace` to search for a word match within a line of a text file. If it is found, I would like to replace the entire line.  My current problem is what I've tried thus far only replaces the exact word and not the entire line.

**PHP**

```
  $database = "1.txt";
  $id = "OFFENSIVEWORD1";
  $str = file_get_contents($database);
  $str = preg_replace("/\b".$id."\b/","********",$str);
  $fp = fopen($database,'w');
  fwrite($fp,$str);
  fclose($fp);
```

**1.TXT FILE**

```
LOVING YOU MY FRIEND etc.
OFFENSIVEWORD1 YOU MY FRIEND etc.
OFFENSIVEWORD2 YOU MY FRIEND etc.
OFFENSIVEWORD3 YOU MY FRIEND etc.
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
LOVING YOU MY FRIEND etc.
********
OFFENSIVEWORD2 YOU MY FRIEND etc.
OFFENSIVEWORD3 YOU MY FRIEND etc.
```

Thanks.

Comment: extreme feelings for your friends...

Comment: use file() instead.. you will get an array.. loop throught the array and replace the sentence.. and insert to a file again..

Comment: @Dinesh can you make me the full code? thanks

Comment: @FilipinoAutoliker That's not how S/O works...

Comment: @Leigh the edit makes this question look pointless

Comment: @Ejay - Actually most of the changes were from a previous edit by someone else. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: @Leigh ah, didn't realize that :) Edits done

Comment: @Cole Johnson any particular reason for rolling back my edits? Does this question make sense to you **now**?

Comment: @Ejay no. It doesn't make sense either way to me.

Comment: then you're not reading it closely. Please try going through the revisions and understanding the question.

Comment: @Ejay - Cool, your (now restored) edit makes more sense than using all symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change

```
$str = preg_replace("/\b".$id."\b/","********",$str);
```

to

```
$str = preg_replace("/\b" . $id . "\b.*\n/ui", "********\n", $str);
```

to make it work. Look out for the difference between *newline* among different operating systems.

### update

or better use

```
$str = preg_replace("/.*\b" . $id . "\b.*\n/ui", "********\n", $str);
```

in case your offensive word is not in the start of the line.

Comment: Interesting, because most windows applications use `CRLF` while most linux uses `CR`. ;)

Comment: Would this only replace the one line or also the previous lines? Hmm..tried it out and it actually works as expected 0.0 :)

Comment: Aha...saw what you mean about the beginning of the line!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it as well (this is tested and works):

```
<?PHP

$str = "
hello this is PROFANE 1
clean statement";

$lines = explode('
', $str);
$newfile = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {
  // ** change PROFANE 1 and PROFANE 2 obviously to real profane words to filter out
  if (stripos($line, 'PROFANE 1') !== false || stripos($line, 'PROFANE 2') !== false) {
    $line = preg_replace("/./", "*", $line);
  }
  $newfile .= '
' . $line;

}

echo "<pre>" . $newfile . "</pre>";

?>
```