# PHP - Replace all text after two specific characters

Tags: php, regex, search, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to do a search/replace on a string with several lines using PHP. I need to check every line and if the line contains double slashes, remove it and all text after, but keep next line intact.

**Sample text:**

Sample of text line 1
Sample of text line 2  // to be removed, including the double slashes
Sample of text line 3

**Expected output:**

Sample of text line 1
Sample of text line 2
Sample of text line 3

No need to remove the blank space before the double slashes.

I've found this solution:

[PHP change whole line if a word exist in a line of .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983498/php-change-whole-line-if-a-word-exist-in-a-line-of-txt-file)

It almost fits my needs, the problem is that it replaces the whole line, not only the desired text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression on every line:

```
$line = preg_replace("/(.*)\/\/.*/","$1",$line);
```

This will replace `Hello // world!` to `Hello`

Answer (score 1):

While I do not use PHP, you can always replace the all the matches of the following regex:

```
\/\/.*
```

Note that you need to make sure the "single line" flag (where dot matches newline) is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex in `preg_match` and replace them with `''`

```
/\/\/[^\r\n]*/ig
```

You can check it here https://regex101.com/r/MC6OcN/2

Answer (score 0):

Use the match reset metacharacter after greedily matching all characters before the first occurring double forward slash, then match the double forward slash and any remaining characters and then replace that match with an empty string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lapqj))

```
echo preg_replace('#.*\K//.*#', '', $text);
```